# How can select all data points that fall beneath a specified sloped line?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I've created a pseudo plot because my actual plot contains hundreds of data. I would like the data points in my plot that are below the line to be a different color then the points above the line. I'm having difficulties changing the color beneath the sloped side of the line.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = (6, 4, 10, 7, 11, 9, 7.5, 4.5, 6.5)
y = (10, 7, 13, 10, 9, 10, 11.5, 8.6, 14)
plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.axhline(y=9, xmax=.3, color = 'black', linestyle = '--')
x_1, y_1 =  [6, 11], [9, 16]
plt.plot(x_1, y_1, linestyle ='--', c='black')
```

Working with my actual data, I was able to get a part of the data plotted beneath the line to be a diffent color. I used...

```
filter = (x < 4) & (y > 28.81)
ax1.scatter(x[filter], y[filter], color='navy', alpha = .2)
```

However, it's that area beneath the slope that's giving me a hard time.

Picture of my real plot:

[image]

Comment: How is the sloped line defined? This is more a math question than a programming question. You have already solved the programming part.

Answer (score 0):

For the values and slope you give in the example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [6, 4, 10, 7, 11, 9, 7.5, 4.5, 6.5]
y = [10, 7, 13, 10, 9, 10, 11.5, 8.6, 14]

newList = zip(x, y)                               #zip x and y to create single points
slope = 7/5                                       #define the slope 
for i in newList:                                 #iterante through the zipped tuples
    a, b = i
    if a <= 6 and b <= 9:                         
        plt.scatter(a, b, c='red', alpha=.5)         
    elif ((b - 9) < (slope * (a - 6))):           #shift the whole plot so (x,y) origin of slope is (0,0) and check tuples below slope  
        plt.scatter(a, b, c='red', alpha=.5)
    else:
        plt.scatter(a, b, c='blue')

plt.axhline(y=9, xmax=.3, color = 'black', linestyle = '--')
x_1, y_1 =  [6, 11], [9, 16]
plt.plot(x_1, y_1, linestyle ='--', c='black')
```

output:

[image: OUT]

Comment: Thank you so much!!! This is perfect. I was able to modify your code to fit my data. 
It looks amazing.